# How do I get the list of login stems for configured backends in python-social-auth?

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-rest-framework, python-social-auth

I have a Django project running `django-rest-framework` to provide a backend for BackboneJS application. I am trying to implement `python-social-auth` to authenticate the app via AJAX.

I need to send via AJAX a list of possible login urls to render in the BackboneJS view e.g.

```
{ 'login_urls' : [
    "https://mydjangoserver.com/login/google-oauth2/",
    "https://mydjangoserver.com/login/facebook/", 
    ...] 
}
```

but to do this I need access this data on the backend in Django. I can access the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting but this only gives a list of strings containing references to modules - how would I convert these to urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the heads up from mariodev, the buried `social.backends.utils` module contains a function to extract the backends from the configured settings ...

```
from social.backends.utils import load_backends
import myprojectname.settings as settings

backends = load_backends(settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS)
login_urls = ['//%s/login/%s/' % (settings.MY_SERVER_HOSTNAME, name) for name in backend.keys()]
```

Comment: `login_urls = [request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('social:begin', args=(backend.name))) for backend in load_backends(settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS)]`

Answer (score 2):

Using django example app utils (needs request object):

```
from social.backends.utils import user_backends_data
from social.apps.django_app.utils import Storage, BACKENDS

for name, backend in user_backends_data(request.user, BACKENDS, Storage).items():
    print backend.AUTHORIZATION_URL
```

I haven't tested this. It's based purely on the `python-social-auth` source code analysis.

Comment: Ah I had completely missed that utils module buried in amongst all the backend modules. In there is another function `load_backends` which does not require an instance of user to work - see my answer. Thanks for the heads up!